# Implement static inner interface as anonymous class in Scala

Tags: scala, interface, static, nested, java-7

I'd like to use NIO.2 features with Scala (classes are in java.nio.file):

In Java I would do:

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/tmp"), new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
  @Override
  public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
    return false;
  }
});
```

How can I do same in Scala? The `Fitler` is static interface inside`DirectoryStream` interface.

Thank you.

EDIT: Please do not reply if you want to suggest me another library/method for listing files. I'm mainly interested in the main problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not 100% sure whether you are asking for a literal conversion of this code in scala:

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/tmp"), new DirectoryStream.Filter[Path] {
  def accept(entry: Path) = false
})
```

..or something else? You could add an implicit conversion:

```
class PathPredicateFilter(p: Path => Boolean) 
  extends DirectoryStream.Filter[Path] {
  def accept(entry: Path) = p(entry)
}
implicit def PathPredicate_Is_DirectoryStreamFilter(p: Path => Boolean) 
  = new PathPredicateFilter(p)
```

Now you can do this:

```
Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/tmp"), (p: Path) => false /* your code here */)
```

Comment: Damnit. Yes I wanted literal conversion because I think I've tried every possible syntax combination and googled very hard. Thank you very much.